# Is it possible to run a for loop into a .then with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, promise, protractor

Is it possible to run a for loop into a .then with Protractor?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
element.all(by.css('.select2-results li')).then(function(item) {
    for(i = 0; i < item.lenght; i++){
        browser.actions().mouseMove(item[i]).perform(); 
        browser.sleep(500); 
    }
});
```

But it seems Protractor is ignoring the for loop, could you help me please?

I used .each but when I ran it I've got this:

```
StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c
    29),platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
    cktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/
    stale_element_reference.html
    Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
    System info: host: 'AVANTEK-PC01', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.
    arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
    Session ID: 3f5e0df8acf94705c936176f21bb05bd
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=WIN8, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, brows
    erName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\MARCEL~1.ORT\AppData\Local\Temp\scop
    ed_dir208_14914}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationE
    nabled=false, version=43.0.2357.130, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled
    =true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false
    , webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, take
    sScreenshot=true}]
```

The code I used is this:

```
  element.all(by.css('.select2-results li')).each(function(elm) {
         browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
         browser.sleep(500);
         var el = elm.getAttribute('class');
         expect(el).toContain('select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted');
         expect(elm.getCssValue('background-color')).toEqual('rgba(114, 101, 91, 1)');
         elm.click();
    });
```

Comment: Is it just the "lenght" -> "length" typo?  The `for` loop itself should be fine in  a `then` handler.  (I believe this one will queue up "length" promises to do the mouseMove().)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a for loop, a more "protractoric" solution would be to use [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

> Calls the input function on each ElementFinder represented by the ElementArrayFinder.

```
element.all(by.css('.select2-results li')).each(function(elm) {
    browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform(); 
    browser.sleep(500); 
});
```